# search on google with the help of image from android phone

Tags: android

Is it Possible to Search on Google with the help of Image from android App that upload the image to google gallery and then search for it and returns the information to the App in the backend like Asyntask method of doinbackground() ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an named Google Goggles . And currently it is the best image search app available .
Google has vast number of  APIs you can search it there .
    https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Read about this .